# php library generate thumbnail from video issue

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am trying to create `thumbnail` image from a `MP4` file using `ffmpeg` `php` library.

I have

```
 $ffmpeg ="/usr/bin/ffmpeg";

 $image_source_path = '/project/a1/a1.mp4';

 $ALL_PLACE_WIDTH = 300;
 $ALL_PLACE_HEIGHT = 270;

 $image_cmd = " -r 1 -r 0.0001 -s ".$ALL_PLACE_WIDTH."x".$ALL_PLACE_HEIGHT." -f image2 ";

 $dest_image_path = '/project/a1/foo-%03d.png';

 $str_command= $ffmpeg  ." -i " . $image_source_path . $image_cmd .$dest_image_path;

 shell_exec($str_command);
```

I only need the first frame of the video but my codes would generate 2 images of the video which is not what I desired. Can anyone help me about the problem?

thanks so much!